# How to handle blur event with click event jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a html markup like this

```
<li id="fSearch" class="alwsShown">
            <div class="dark overflowHidden" id="fSearchBg">
                            <input type="text" id="filter" name="" style="width:140px" tabindex="1" class="fullWidth opt resetBorderNShd resetShd" value="" autocomplete="off" title="Search" value=""/>
             <span id="stopSearch" class="imgSprite stopSearch displayNone poAbs"></span>
            </div>

          </li>
```

Used jquery

```
var test = function() {
    var self = this,
    $filter = $("#filter"),
    $fSearchBg = $("#fSearchBg"),
    $stopSearch = $(".stopSearch");
    // Blur
    $filter.blur(function() {
      $filteranimate({
        width: "140px"
      }, 200, function() {
        $fSearchBg.removeClass("light").addClass("dark");
        $stopSearch.hide();
      });
    });
    $stopSearch.click(function(event){
      $filter.val("");
      $(this).hide('fast');
      event.preventDefault()
      event.stopPropagation();

    });
    // Focus
    $filter.focus(function() {
      // animate
      $filter.animate({
        width: "285px"
      }, 200);
      $fSearchBg.removeClass("dark").addClass("light");
    });

  });
```

In my case my input box is having 140px of width, when a user focus on input box I am animating it to 284px and when i click anywhere I am handling a blur event. Now my requirement is there is a cross icon inside input box when i click on cross icon, I have to perform some task but I didn't want to fire blur when i click on cross icon. please suggest me how to handle click if already there is a blur event.

Comment: which one is the cross icon on the markup?

Comment: <span id="stopSearch" class="imgSprite stopSearch displayNone poAbs"></span> this is markup which i am using for cross icon and $stopSearch.click(function(event){}) here is the event.

Comment: can you also add a fiddle with the correct styling? it will help speed up in finding a solution.

Comment: untested, but try bind blur to `stopSearch` too. `$filter = $("#filter, #stopSearch")`

Answer (score 1):

If you can detect the icon click set some global javascript flag like

```
iconclicked = true;
```

Use this iconclicked in blur method and return if it is true